# Samba configuration file

Tags: networking, raspbmc, samba

I'm attempting to set up a NAS using samba on my raspberry pi, running raspbmc. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/) to do so. I've got to the stage of editing the config file:

> Our next stop is to turn on user authentication for our samba storage, otherwise anyone with general access to our network (like guest Wi-Fi users) will be able to walk right in. Scroll down in the Samba config file until you get to the section that reads:

However, when I open the config file in nano, I get a completely different file to that shown in the tutorial. Here is my configuration file (I have attempted to modify it myself but I must have done so wrong)

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
usershare allow guests = yes
security=share
security=user
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = no
unix extensions = no
#lock directory = /var/cache/samba
[pi]
browsable = yes
read only = no
#guest ok = yes
valid users = pi
path = /home/pi
#force user = pi (no longer needed)
[devices]
browsable = yes
read only = no
#guest ok = yes
valid users = pi
path = /media
force user = root
[Backup]
comment = Backup folder
path = /media/750GB\ Hard\ drive/Backup
valid users = @users
force group = users
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0771
read only = no
```

Backup is the folder I want to share.
Unless you guys think it's particularly important, I wouldn't mind there being no security on it because my wifi is secure and there's nobody that has access.

Let me know if I've missed anything, I'm fairly new to linux so I'm not 100% what I'm doing yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

hi there are some errors in the config.

you can validate this also with

```
 testparm /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

firstly in the [global] section you write

security=share
security=user
i dont know which will be accepted, but if you want to use no security remove the security = user.
then in the [backup] section you want to set the valid users should be a member of the user group (@ refers to a group) this will not work. remove it

this both points should help you to fix the issue

but another hint: i am not sure if working with spaces in foldernames is best idea. this is very windows style. on linux os it should work, but you will always see the escaped space. i would remove the spaces. (but it should not be a part of the problem)